# How to query against time using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, query, time

I have a date-time field in a feature class which I want to query. The field has values like "2011-01-01 00:00:29".

I want to query the data between the time 00:06:00 and 00:12:00. The date does not matter an shall be ignored.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a little play around with your problem and have come up with a solution of sorts. Working with dates and times is always a pain and doubly so in ArcGIS as it has really limited support for these data types. I would love to see some other solutions to this problem as I am probably making this more complex than it needs to be.

In SQL you could just select this data (assuming it is correctly formatted in the DateTime format) using a `BETWEEN` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [TIME_FIELD] BETWEEN '00:06:00' AND '00:12:00'
```

But in ArcGIS this is not possible (I think because of the *.dbf format at the heart of shapefiles) as the only way to store the dates and times you have are as strings.

However we can use field calculator and a Python command to separate the date from the time and then remove the colons from between the hours minutes and seconds and finally cast it to an integer.

```
int(''.join(!date_time!.split(' ')[1].split(':')))
```

(!date_time! is the name of the field containing the date/time strings)

This means that a value of `00:06:00` will be represented in a new field as `600` and a value of `00:12:00` will be stored as `1200`.

From these integers we can perform a selection using a modification of the above SQL query to find the correct points:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE:
"time_int" > 600 AND "time_int"< 1200
```